# tensorflow : How to outer product when the tensor's first dim is None?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I have a tensor whose shape is `None,10` . I want to get a outer product result whose shape is `None,100` or `None,10,10` . Here is my code :

```
# output'shape is None,10
output = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()(encoded_feature_list)
# wrong
cross_output = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x:tf.linalg.matmul(x,x,transpose_a=True))(output)
cross_output = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(cross_output)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Outer product in tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33858021/outer-product-in-tensorflow)

Comment: @DavidS no , it's not . its first dim isn't ```None``` ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer I provided does have the answer, but not the immediate one!

Given the example you gave in your comment to @Meow Cat 2012:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2,3.0],[4,5,6.0]]
res = tf.einsum('ki,kj->kij',a,a)
print(res.shape)  # TensorShape([2, 3, 3])
```

[`tf.einsum()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/einsum) function will compute the outer product of two tensors.

Another solution using [`tf.linalg.matmul`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/linalg/matmul) is (@DachuanZhao pointed it out):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
    
a = np.array([[1,2,3.0],[4,5,6.0]]
res = tf.linalg.matmul(tf.expand_dims(a, axis=-1),tf.expand_dims(a, axis=1))
print(res.shape)  # (2, 3, 3)
```

Comment: Yes , I have found anther solution :

Comment: ```tf.linalg.matmul(tf.expand_dims(a, axis=-1),tf.expand_dims(a, axis=1))```

Comment: @DachuanZhao Cool, happy you managed. I will add this solution to my answer for future users

Answer (score 0):

Already answered: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51323886/9399618

According to the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tensordot):

> Additionally outer product is supported by passing axes=0

Tested as follow:

```py
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.0])
tf.tensordot(a, a, axes=0)
# Got <tf.Tensor: shape=(10, 10), dtype=float64, numpy=xxx>
```

Comment: This is coeerct dim=1 , but get wrong result when dim=2 .

Comment: When ```a = np.array([[1,2,3.0],[4,5,6.0]])``` , 
```tf.tensordot(a, a, axes=0)``` get the shape ```(2,3,2,3)``` , not ```(2,3,3)``` or ```(2,9)```